# How do I read a csv value with an If then statement?

Tags: python, csv

I want to read the csv file value for 'Rel volume' and then print the ticker and value if the value is 2.5 or greater. However, I cannot do this because the int value cannot be compared to a 'str' value. How can I compare the values, and then put the values of the csv file from the respective stock ticker into a new list?
Here is my code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


write_header = True

twiturl = "https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog"
twitpage = urllib.request.urlopen(twiturl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(twitpage,"html.parser")

print(soup.title.text)

tweets = [i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')]
""""
print(tweets)
"""
URL_BASE = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="

with open('_Stocks.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # note the change
    for tckr in tweets:
        URL = URL_BASE + tckr
        try:
            fpage = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage, 'html.parser')

            if write_header:
                # note the change
                writer.writerow(['tckr'] + list(map(lambda e: e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class': 'snapshot-td2-cp'}))))
                write_header = False

            # note the change
            writer.writerow([tckr] + list(map(lambda e: e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class': 'snapshot-td2'}))))
        except urllib.request.HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(URL))

with open('_Stocks.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        if line['Rel Volume'] > 2.5:
            print(line['tckr'], line['Rel Volume'])
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the value to a number yet?

Comment: Note that everything before the `with open(...) as csv_file:` line is irrelevant to the question, and can safely be removed. You can reproduce your problem with the last 6 lines alone.

Comment: It should work with float(line[. . .]) > 2.5. Also just use pandas to load pandas to load your csv files. It‘s much more elegant then looping over the lines.

Comment: Thank you for the help @dennis-ec

Answer (score 0):

When reading data using `csv.DictReader()`, the values are all strings. As such you would need to convert `Rel Volume` into a float before using it:

```
with open('_Stocks.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        line['Rel Volume'] = float(line['Rel Volume'])

        if line['Rel Volume'] > 2.5:
            print(line['tckr'], line['Rel Volume'])
```